# Best way to handle single user authentication?

Tags: symfony, authentication, symfony-2.5

I'm working on a small app with Symfony 2.5, and I'd like to know what is the best way to handle security, but just for only one user. I could do this with an `.htaccess` but maybe their exists some light and quickly installable sf2 bundle which could do the job. I don't want role stuff, or profile, just a way to authenticate myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symfony2 let's you easily use http authentication. Together with the `in_memory` provider, you have a perfect solution for your use case.

From [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#basic-example-http-authentication):

```
security:
    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            http_basic:
                realm: "Secured Demo Area"

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin/, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
        # Include the following line to also secure the /admin path itself
        # - { path: ^/admin$, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

    providers:
        in_memory:
            memory:
                users:
                    ryan:  { password: ryanpass, roles: 'ROLE_USER' }
                    admin: { password: kitten, roles: 'ROLE_ADMIN' }

    encoders:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext
```

Comment: Oh, I missed that. I think it will do the job. Thanks !